# Solving $\sin x=2\sin(2\pi/3-x)$

Tags: trigonometry

How can I solve the equation: $$\sin x=2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}-x\right)$$

Without using the formula:

$$\sin(a-b)=\sin a \cos b-\sin b \cos a$$?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with complex analysis?

Comment: No, we didn't learn this matiral yet.

Comment: Can you use the equivalent formula for $\cos$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the next picture

[image]

By Sine Law the equality $\frac{\sin x}{2} = \frac{\sin\left(2\pi/3-x\right)}{1}$ holds, then by using the Cosine Law we have
\begin{align*}
c^2&=5-4\cos\frac{\pi}{3}\\
&=3\\
c&=\sqrt{3}
\end{align*}
Now, from Sine Law, it follows.
\begin{align*}
\sin x&=\frac{2\sin \pi/3}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\sin x&=1\\
\implies x&=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: That's very nice +1